# Prolog: insert data structures into list using DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

This question contains some examples from [this webpage](http://kti.ms.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/basic_struct.html)

I created a data structures date(Year,Month,Day) in Prolog:

```
make_date(Y,M,D,date(Y,M,D)).
```

I then created get_x to access components of the data structure:

```
get_year(date(Y,_,_),Y).
get_month(date(_,M,_),M).
get_day(date(_,_,D),D).
```

Then I created set_x to test or generate components of the data structure:

```
set_year(Y,date(_,M,D),date(Y,M,D)).
set_month(M,date(Y,_,D),date(Y,M,D)).
set_day(D,date(Y,M,_),date(Y,M,D)).
```

How can I use DCG rules to store the variables (Y, M, and D) in a list?

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to do from a query perspective? Why do you think you need a DCG? For example, could just write, `date_list(date(Y,M,D), [Y,M,D]).`

Comment: `date(date(Y,M,D)) --> [Y, M, D]`?

Comment: If you were using `dcg/basics.pl`, then perhaps `date(date(Y,M,D)) --> integer(Y), "-", integer(M), "-", integer(D).` although you probably want to support better formatting and do more thinking before you accept some random integer in each of those fields.

Comment: The reason why I chose to use DCGs is because the variables come from several sentences that are parsed using DCG rules. Once I have stored the variables in the list, I want to constrain them using the CLP(FD) library, along with labeling/2.

Comment: All those OOPs (make_, get_, set_...) interfaces are really useless in Prolog. It's about a *different* paradigm...